# Different results obtained by using generic lambdas and automatic return type feature in C++14

Tags: python, c++, lambda, c++14

I am trying to realize this piece of high-order function in python using C++:

```
def add1(x):
    def helper():
        nonlocal x
        x += 1
        return x
    return helper
```

Here are the three versions I created:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

function<int(void)> add1_v1(int x) {
    function<int(void)> g = [&x]() {return ++x;};
    return g;
}

auto add1_v2(int x) {
    function<int(void)> g = [&x]() {return ++x;};
    return g;
}

auto add1_v3(int x) {
    auto g = [&x]() {return ++x;};
    return g;
}

int main() {
  auto a = add1_v1(100);
  auto b = add1_v2(100);
  auto c = add1_v3(100);
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      cout << a() << endl;
  }
  cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      cout << b() << endl;
  }
  cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      cout << c() << endl;
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

The outputs are:

```
101
102
103
-------------------------------------------
4239465
4239466
4239467
-------------------------------------------
4201325
4201325
4201325
```

Only add1_v1 matches what I want. Can anyone explain the reason for me?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: @Brian Have revised the problem.

Comment: They're all wrong. `add1_v1` got lucky.

Comment: @immibis @Sam Varshavchik @songyuanyao  I didn't realize there is a `mutable` modifier in lambda expressions in C++. Thanks all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that this is undefined behavior.

The inner lambda captures `x` by reference.

The problem is that as soon as `add()` returns, its parameter gets destroyed, and the returned lambda has a dangling reference to a destroyed object.

The lambda must capture `x` by value; and what it looks to me you're really trying to do here is a [mutable lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
auto add(int x) {
    function<int(void)> g = [x]() mutable {return ++x;};
    return g;
}
```

Note that this approach carries certain implications when it comes to subsequently copying the returned lambda; but as long as the returned lambda remains "in one place", throughout its remaining lifetime, the resulting semantics will probably be what you expect.

Comment: `auto long_live_x = make_shared<int>(x); return [=]() {return ++*long_live_x;};` is also possible, with different trade-offs.

Answer (score 4):

All of them are ill-formed, because you're capturing `x` by reference in lambda, but `x` is a local variable and would be destroyed when get out of the function `add`, then the reference becomes dangle, dereference on it latter causes UB, which means anything is possible; even the 1st case seems works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, seems all version of functions works well if you change parameter signature to add1_v*(int&& x)